# Sub-class doesn't work,Why is it?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
     function inherit(p){
        if(p == null) throw TypeError();
        if(Object.create) return Object.create(p);
        var t = typeof p;
        if(t != "function" || t != "object") throw TypeError();
        function f(){};
        f.prototype = p;
        return new f;
    }


    function Super_class(){
        this.Sup_prop = "I'm superclass";
        this.Sup_prop2 = "I'm superclass2";
    }
    Super_class.prototype.Hello = function(){ alert("Hello"); };


    function Sub_class(){
        this.sub_prop = "I'm subclass";
        this.sub_prop2 = "I'm subclass 2";
    }
    Sub_class.prototype = inherit(Super_class);
    Sub_class.prototype.constructor = Sub_class;

    var x = new Sub_class;
    x.Hello();
```

This code from Javascript The Definitive Guide book that explain about how to create a sub-class,but it doesn't work.

I've ever seen code about how to create a sub-class in this website.

```
    function Super_class(){
        this.Sup_prop = "I'm superclass";
        this.Sup_prop2 = "I'm superclass2";
    }
    Super_class.prototype.Hello = function(){ alert("Hello"); };


    function Sub_class(){
        this.sub_prop = "I'm subclass";
        this.sub_prop2 = "I'm subclass 2";
    }
    Sub_class.prototype = new Super_class;

    var x = new Sub_class; // change here
    x.Hello();// It work!!
```

I'd like to know why code in my book doesn't work.My book has mistake or I'm wrong.

P.S My writing in English is not good,I'm sorry.

**UPDATE** 
This is my first example above.

```
    Sub_class.prototype = inherit(Super_class);
    Sub_class.prototype.constructor = Sub_class; //Why did set be Sub_class??
```

I'd like to know why did "Sub_class.prototype.constructor" set be Sub_class?
My book didn't have explanation about it.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What are the symptoms?

Comment: Alert doesn't work.It have error message "hasn't method Hello" when I've tested in a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing

```
Super_class.prototype
```

rather than `Super_class` to the inherit function.  It appears to expect a prototype object, not the function itself

Comment: This is wrong. The entire argument list (including the parentheses) is optional. See, for example, the [Mozilla reference page for the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Comment: @TedHopp I agree with you. It doesn't has parameter,It can avoid.

Comment: @TedHopp Yep I realized my mistake.  Had never seen that syntax before.  I realized I was wrong about the issue when I tested it in a fiddle.

Comment: @ben336 Thanks a lot!!,It work. I would like to know something. Could you tell me why "Sub_class.prototype.constructor" set be "Sub_class" ??.My book doesn't has explanation about this.

Comment: @Domino sorry I don't understand your question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ben336 Don't worry,It's my mistake. I'm bad in English. I've updated in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `inherit` function, specifically with this line:

```
if(Object.create) return Object.create(p);
```

This returns a new object with it's prototype set to `p`. However, `p` is not an instance of `Super_class`; it's the function `Super_class`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `inherit` when it receives an object as a parameter, but when it receives a function, you don't want to be using `Object.create`. Try this to start with for `inherit`:

```
function inherit(p) {
    if (typeof p === 'function') {
        return new p;
    }
    throw TypeError()
}
```